# Calculation between “my current geolocation” and other coordinates

Tags: javascript, math, web-applications, geolocation, geospatial

How can I calculate the distance between “my current geolocation” (the coordinate I get using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition) and say 10 others (fixed) coordinates simultaneously?

I want to track the distance so if “my current geolocation” get within a specific radius of one the coordinates ==> something amazing happens.

Can I solve this problem using the Haversine Distance Formula?

All the calculations will be within a smaller area (a city) so I need to get the results in meters rather than kilometers.

Thank you for your time and input !

/a.

Answer (score 0):

The harvesine formula is just a special formula. But it works for your question.  If you want better result you can try the vincenty formula. It uses an ellipsoid earth. Just loop over every point and compute the distance from it.

Comment: Or can I use Google Maps API for the same function ?

Comment: What do you mean? There is Google Direction Api. If this is what you mean, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

At the equator 5 decimal places in your coordinate(0.00001) = 1.1057 meters Latidude &1.1132 meters Longitude.

As the coordinates move from the equator to the poles the Longitude value decreases.

```
Degree| Latidude | Longitude
------------------------------
0°    | 1.1057 m |1.1132 m
15°   | 1.1064 m |1.0755 m
30°   | 1.1085 m |0.9648 m
45°   | 1.1113 m |0.7884 m
60°   | 1.1141 m |0.5580 m
75°   | 1.1161 m |0.2890 m
90°   | 1.1169 m |0.0000 m
```

If your distances are small you can either use Pythagoras with correction for latidude or use Haversine.

The following code uses Haversine

```
var lat1 =55.00001;//Point 1 nearest
var lng1 =-2.00001  ; 
//var lat1 =55.00002;//Point 2 nearest
//var lng1 =-2.00002    ; 

//Array of points
var coordArray = [[55.00000,-2.00000],[55.00003,-2.00003],[55.00006,-2.00006],[55.00009,-2.00009],[55.00012,-2.00012]];

function toRad(Value) {
    /** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}

function Round(Number, DecimalPlaces) {
    return Math.round(parseFloat(Number) * Math.pow(10, DecimalPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, DecimalPlaces);
}
function haversine(lat1,lat2,lng1,lng2){
    rad = 6371000; // meters
    deltaLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    deltaLng = toRad(lng2-lng1);
    lat1 = toRad(lat1);
    lat2 = toRad(lat2);
    a = Math.sin(deltaLat/2) * Math.sin(deltaLat/2) + Math.sin(deltaLng/2) * Math.sin(deltaLng/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return  rad * c;
}
function calculate(){
    var result = haversine(lat1,coordArray [0][0],lng1,coordArray [0][1]);
    var index = 0;
    for (var i=1;i<coordArray.length;i++){ 
        var ans = haversine(lat1,coordArray [i][0],lng1,coordArray [i][1]);
        if (ans < result){
            result = ans;
            index++;
        }   

    }
    document.write("Result = " +Round(result,2)+ " Meters Point = "+ (index+1));
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDx7c/)

Comment: Did it fully answer your question??